# $scenario var in functional test error with Yii2 and Codeception

Tags: php, testing, yii, yii2, codeception

I am trying to write functional tests but I am getting the error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined variable: scenario
```

My test looks like this:

```
<?php

use tests\functional;

class AccountTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
/**
 * @var \FunctionalTester
 */
protected $tester;

protected $url = 'http://domain.api/v1/api';

// tests
public function testMe()
{
    $I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //remove
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); //remove
    $I->sendPost('/account/register');
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
  }

}
```

What do I need to add for $scenario to be available?

Comment: OK, I got a step further when I created the test by running "codecept generate:cept functional account/Account" . However most methods are not available to me such as sendPost().

Comment: Did you run `codecept build`? Take a look at the tests provided with the [advanced application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced)

Answer (score 0):

Give your `testMe()` method the arguments `$I` and `$scenario`:

```
public function($I, $scenario)
{
    [...]
}
```

You don't need to instantiate the `FunctionalTester()` then.

Comment: That gives me this error: PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Missing argument 1 for AccountTest::testMe().  I guess no parameters are being passed to the method.